# What regex will match either 2 digits, or 3 digits starting with 0?

Tags: .net, regex

Must be:

- all digits.
- 2 or 3 positions.
- if 3 positions, first character must be '0'.

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be along the lines of:

```
^0?\d{2}$
```

What you're asking for (paraphrased) is any two digits with an optional `0` of the front. The anchors (`^` and `$`) may not be necessary depending on the regex function being called - I've included them to ensure that a string like `ABC011DEF` won't match.

Comment: @Berryl: I was in the middle of having breakfast. Apologies for the delay :-)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

`"^(0\d{2,3}|\d{2})$"`